# Calling Related Object of the Entity from ASP.Net Web Api OData Controller

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm writing ASP.Net Web Api OData for Northwind Database.
Here is my method in  Controller.

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Order> GetOrdersFromCustomer([FromODataUri] string key)
{
   // return _Context.Orders.Where(o => o.CustomerID == key);
    return _Context.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID.Equals(key)).SelectMany(c => c.Orders);
}
```

This is my configuration code in WebApiConfig.cs.

```
     public static class WebApiConfig
     {
         public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
         {
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("Northwind", "odata", GetImplicitEDM());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
       }

      private static IEdmModel GetImplicitEDM()
      {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
        builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
        return builder.GetEdmModel(); // magic happens here
      }
```

This is my Order.cs

```
  public class Order
  {
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RequiredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShippedDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
  }
```

This is my Customer.cs.

```
    public class Customer
    {
     public string CustomerID { get; set; }
     public string CompanyName { get; set; }
     public string ContactName { get; set; }
     public string Phone { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string PostalCode { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my request url.

http://localhost:21288/odata/Customers('ALFKI')/Orders

Every time I call this request, I get this exception ( status code 500).  I write and check everything like sample code. But their code works perfectly and my code doesn't work.

```
"odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"An error has occurred."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8'.","type":"System.InvalidOperationException","stacktrace":"","internalexception":{
        "message":"Null collections cannot be serialized.","type":"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException"
```

I don't know what is wrong. plz help me.

Comment: I am getting the same error message.
Did you manage to find a reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think your

```
_Context.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID.Equals(key)).SelectMany(c => c.Orders);
```

can not convert to `IQueryable<Order>`, so return null, and get the exception, try:

```
_Context.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID.Equals(key)).SelectMany(c => c.Orders).AsQueryable();
```